# Is there a warning for undocumented sections?

Tags: rust, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am writing a crate that I plan to publish. When publishing, one of the most important thing (in my opinion) is to ensure the crate is well documented. Therefore my question : is there a warning to be turned on which warms undocumented sections of the code ?

---

E.g.: I typically think of something like `#[warn(undocumented)]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, such a lint exists. The rustc compiler provides the [`missing_docs` lint](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#missing-docs), which warns about missing documentation on public items when enabled. The clippy linter provides the [`missing_docs_in_private_items` lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#missing_docs_in_private_items), which additionally warns… well, you guessed it. Note that `missing_docs_in_private_items` warns for all items, so you don't need `missing_docs` if you enable it.

You can enable the lints using

```
#![warn(missing_docs)]
#![warn(clippy::missing_docs_in_private_items)]
```

for warnings or

```
#![deny(missing_docs)]
#![deny(clippy::missing_docs_in_private_items)]
```

for errors.

Comment: Note that this has been moved into clippy - you need to use `clippy::missing_docks_in_private_items` and the errors will only show up if you run `cargo clippy`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [**missing-docs** lint](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#missing-docs) in the Rust compiler.

Example:

```rust
#![warn(missing_docs)]

fn foo(bar: i32) {}
```

The output from the compiler:

```
warning: missing documentation for crate
 --> src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | / #![warn(missing_docs)]
2 | |
3 | | fn foo(bar: i32) {}
  | |___________________^
  |
```

You may also find [more lints in the rustc book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/index.html).